# No Pocket icon in Firefox although it's installed and active ("true")

Tags: firefox, firefox-extensions

I've installed Ubuntu 14: on Firefox i can't see the Pocket icon - although it's installed and activated ("true" in about:config). I've logged on by web, but it's not the same. 
Anyone has the same problem and knows the solution?

thanks in advance

Luciano

Comment: please let me know my answer is use ful to you?..If yes please accept my answr

Answer (score 0):

**Make sure Pocket for Firefox is available in your region:**

Pocket for Firefox is currently available in English (U.S.), German, Japanese, Russian and Spanish (Spain) versions of Firefox 38.0.5 and up. If your language is not on the list, stay tuned.

**Disable the old Pocket add-on:**

Pocket for Firefox is disabled by default if you already have the Pocket add-on. The old add-on will no longer receive security or feature updates in countries where Pocket for Firefox is available.

1.Click the menu button menu , followed by Add-ons.

2.Go to the Extensions panel.

3.Click the <kbd>Disable</kbd> button for Pocket.

4.Restart Firefox. The new Pocket button will appear in your toolbar when Firefox restarts.

**Move the Pocket button to your toolbar or menu**

After you've disabled the old add-on and verified that you're in a supported locale, activate Pocket for Firefox by following these steps:

1. Click on the menu button ,then click  <kbd>+ customize</kbd>
2. Drag the Pocket button to your favorite spot on the toolbar or menu panel.

[image: img]
<sub>(source: [mozilla.net](https://support.cdn.mozilla.net/media/uploads/gallery/images/2015-05-14-15-12-17-e45df2.png))</sub>

reference [here](https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/kb/where-pocket-button-firefox#w_make-sure-pocket-for-firefox-is-available-in-your-region)

Answer (score 0):

Firefox has Pocket built-in now. You have to make sure you have **version 38.0.5 or later** as @Ravan said. But, if his solution didn't work for you, it may be a problem with your **locale configuration**.
The solution I found [here](https://www.reddit.com/r/firefox/comments/38iafi/trouble_finding_pocket_button/) is:

> ***add your own locale in the about:config string of browser.pocket.enabledLocales***

In my case, I added es-AR, restarted Firefox, and it worked like a charm!!

*You can get your locale config running the `locale` command on a terminal.

Comment: Crontab entry run as root to eliminate pocket every single night at 2:30am:
# m h  dom mon dow   command
30 2 * * * rm -rf /usr/lib/firefox/browser/features/firefox@getpocket.com.xpi For the record, if this causes the browser to malfunction, then those of us who care about security need a new browser. Firefox used to be the best when it came to privacy and security, short of Tor at least. Not so much if what they intend to do is purposefully install a SPAM tool.